# Process.Exited event is not be called

Tags: c#, command-line, process

I have the following code snippet to call into command line:

```
p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/C " + "type " + “[abc].pdf”;

psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.StartInfo = psi;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
p.Start();   
p.WaitForExit();
```

Strangely, When [abc] is a small pdf file(8kb) `p_Exited` is called. But when it's a large pdf file(120kb) it is never called. Any clues?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it wait forever on WaitForExit or it passes the line and ignore the event?

Comment: Seemed wait forever on WaitForExit. No exception occured in between.

Comment: What language is this? It would be helpful to include that in the tags!

Answer (score 2):

You need to consume the output stream when the standard output has been redirected:

```
p.Start();   
p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```