# Process.Exited only fires when using Windows Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, process

I have been trying to solve this for a few days, My program starts a process (GUI Application such as notepad or (metro) Images) like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process execute = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
execute.StartInfo.FileName = (System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"{NR6T7YHYGFDGY77FM74766JTF63IJ78899DV884}\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(App.args[1]));
execute.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
execute.Exited += delegate
{
    File.Delete(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"{NR6T7YHYGFDGY77FM74766JTF63IJ78899DV884}\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(App.args[1]));
    App.Current.Shutdown();
};
execute.Start();
```

then calls `this.Hide()` to become the equivalent of a background process. Now the problem is, if I open a file that opens with Word, Photos(Metro) or any other app that **can** be uninstalled execute.Exited *never fires*. But if I open a file that opens with notepad, paint or  any other app that **can't** be uninstalled execute.Exited *Does* fire.. I have been able to rule out most potential problems:

1. Since `execute.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` the process is raising events.
2. Nothing is blocking my code unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484452/process-exited-is-never-called-even-though-enableraisingevents-is-set-to-true)
3. I have tried using `Process.WaitForExit();` but that doesn't work either

Please Help Guys.

Comment: This has more to do with the file association for the type of file that you open.  Programs like Word and Photos are unusual in the way they get started, has something to do with Explorer stepping in to get the job done.  Which doesn't exit.  Hard to fix no doubt.