# Restarting nodejs as a process in C#

Tags: c#, node.js, process, exit

I am starting NodeJs as a process inside a C# application. My intent is to restart the process every time it stops.

Code for starting the process is:

```
_nodeProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        WorkingDirectory = location,
        FileName = "node.exe",
        Arguments = "main.js"
    }
};

_nodeProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_nodeProcess.Exited += nodeExited;

_nodeProcess.Start();

string stderrStr = _nodeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
string stdoutStr = _nodeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stderrStr))
{
    LogInfoMessage(stderrStr);
}

LogInfoMessage(stdoutStr);
_nodeProcess.WaitForExit();    

_nodeProcess.Close();
```

here is nodeExited method:

```
private void nodeExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isNodeStop)
    {
        this.restartERM_Click(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        _isNodeStop = false;
    }
}
```

_isNodeStop  is just a flag that I set to true when killing a node from the controlled place.

Like this:

```
private void KillNode()
{
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("node"))
    {
        _isNodeStop = true;
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

My problem is that **nodeExited** method does not trigger every time node is stopped. I have no clue why and I could not see any pattern. Is just does not stop most of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WaitForExit() anyway, so there is no reason to use the Exited event.

Just manually call your Handler after WaitForExit() like this:

```
_nodeProcess.WaitForExit();    
_nodeProcess.Close();
nodeExited(_nodeProcess, new EventArgs());
```

and remove

```
_nodeProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_nodeProcess.Exited += nodeExited;
```

Edit:

If I understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484452/process-exited-is-never-called-even-though-enableraisingevents-is-set-to-true) answer correctly, you might also have a deadlock because you call `StandardError.ReadToEnd();` and then `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`. The StandardOutput Buffer might be full before it even reaches that point.

Comment: About Edit: I believe this was not a problem. I will read output first and then the error.