# Process.Exited called only sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

Hi fellow programmers,

I am scratching my head over this one. I am using the following method to start a process. The first is wkhtmltoimage.exe and then wkhtmltopdf.exe. Everything works as expected, except that `Process_Exited` is not always called. During a single run of my program, where I pressed the appropriate button several times, I had all possible variations:

- Only wkhtmltoimage raised the event
- only wkhtmltopdf raised the event
- both did
- the event wasn't raised at all.

Via the task manager and the debugger I could verify that 
the processes were always ended correctly.
Nothing is reproducible, every run is different. This is my first try with processes, maybe I am doing something wrong. Solving this problem is not vital for my application, luckily.

```
protected Process StartProcess(string FileName, string Arguments)
{
    ProcessStartInfo MyStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName, Arguments)
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    };

    Process Proc = new Process { StartInfo = MyStartInfo };
    Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    Proc.Exited += (sender, name) => Process_Exited(Proc, Proc.ProcessName);
    Proc.Start();

    return Proc;
}


protected void Process_Exited(object sender, string ProcessName)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Process_Exited: " + ProcessName);
}
```

Comment: did you try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484452/process-exited-is-never-called-even-though-enableraisingevents-is-set-to-true?lq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768877/process-exited-event-is-not-be-called?rq=1

Comment: Nice finds. My code however is reading the standard output completely. When it doesn't (I can force this), my program hangs right in the line, where the standard output is read. And of course, my process does not exit then and does not fire the event. If my program really would hang, I would notice this in the debugger and I wouldn't be able to repeat the test without restarting my program.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your program is still running when the processes were being exited.

I doubt that your program is being ended, before the Process_Exited is called.

Comment: Yes, I stepped through it via debugger and monitored the task manager. My program was still running and able to catch the events. But thanks for pointing this out.